# finite group theory - combinatorial approach to determine number of subgroups rank 3 from $A_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, recreational-mathematics

How many different subgroups of order $3$ are in alternating group $A_{4}$?

Using direct listing is doable, but primitive. I wonder how to apply combinatorial approach (intuitively it would be much better approach than direct listing)? Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every non-identity element of these subgroups will be of order $3$ per [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)).  One can show that the elements of order $3$ in $A_4$ are precisely the $3$ cycles.  Furthermore, each subgroup will be disjoint sans the identity.  Thus, counting the total number of possible $3$-cycles will almost get you the total number of order $3$ subgroups (you'll have to do an easy correction for the over-counting).

Alternatively, if you're familiar with the [Sylow theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems), they'll give you an answer pretty much immediately without hardly having to think since there're only two factors of $|A_4| = 12$ congruent to $1 \pmod{3}$ .

Comment: Thanks for help! Sylow theorems are too strong tools to deal with such rather easy problem (also thought of using it, but such solution would be artificial, in my opinion).